# Find the elementary divisors of a matrix given its characteristic and minimal polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-functions, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

This question comes from and old exam: Suppose the square rational matrix $A$ has characteristic and minimum polynomials $p_A(x) = x^6(x^2-2)^3(x^2+4)^2$ and $m_A(x) = x^2(x^2-2)(x^2+4)^2$ and $null A = 4$. Determine the elementary divisors of $A$.

So, first of all I'm not sure how to find invariant factors just given these polynomials and not the matrix $A$ itself. I know that $m_A(x)$ is the largest invariant factor of $A$ by definition and $p_A(x)$ is the product of all the invariant factors. Also, I'm assuming all the divisors and factors should be rational here. So, given that $x^2$, $(x^2-2)$, and $(x^2+4)^2$ are surely elementary divisors. However, I'm not sure how to find the rest. Also, the $null A=4$ gives us the geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ which gives us what the jordan blocks corresponding to $0$ are, however, I'm not sure how this helps. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a point about the formulation: [elementary divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_divisors) are associated to a module over a PID, not to a matrix. No doubt what is meant here are the elementary divisors of $K^n$, viewed as $K[X]$-module with the indeterminate $X$ acting as multiplication by the matrix$~A$  (with $K=\Bbb Q$, and $n=16$ if I've computed $\deg(p_A)$ correctly).

Answer (score 6):

Your elementary divisors are primary, so powers of irreducible polynomials. Clearly the irreducible (over $\Bbb Q$) polynomials $x$, $x^2-2$ and $x^2+4$ are the only ones relevant here, and they can be considered independently. For each the power in $p_A$ gives the product of the elementary divisors for this irreducible, and the power in $m_A$ gives the largest factor. So we are looking for a partition of the exponent in $p_A$ with largest part the exponent in $m_A$. For $x^2+4$ that is a partition of $2$ with largest part$~2$, which clearly can only be $(2)$, while for $x^2-2$ that is a partition of $3$ with largest part$~1$, which can only be $(1,1,1)$. For $x$ however there is freedom: for a partition of $6$ with largest part $2$ we can have either $(2,2,2)$ or $(2,2,1,1)$. So here the information about the nullity of $A$ must come to the rescue: since each part for $x$ contributes a Jordan block for $\lambda=0$ and therefore contributes $1$ to the nullity, the $4$-part partition $(2,2,1,1)$ must be the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what can the Jordan normal form of the matrix be.

The nullity is the number of $0$-blocks (each $0$-block contains a single eigenvector). 
The size of these blocks are either $1$ or $2$ (because $x^2\,|\,m_A(x)$) that sum up to $6$. 
For this, the only possibility for the sizes of $0$-blocks is $2,2,1,1$.

The other eigenvalues ($\pm\sqrt2,\ \pm2i$) seem easy to deal with.

This way you will obtain a *unique* Jordan form, which determines the matrix up to similarity.

Comment: So you'll get a Jordan normal form of:

Comment: So you'll get a Jordan normal form of: $J_2(0) \oplus J_2(0) \oplus J_1(0) \oplus J_1(0) \oplus J_1(x^2-2) \oplus J_1(x^2-2) \oplus J_1(x^2-2) \oplus J_2(x^2+4)$. The problem with this is that $\pm \sqrt{2}$ and $\pm 2i$ are irrational numbers and we want the jordan matrix and the invariant factors to be rational so I'm not really seeing how you figure this out from the Jordan form exactly?

Comment: Ah, I thought if you already know the matrix, you can calculate it.